# Why isn't my compiler recognizing my class "index" as a type within the class implementation

Tags: c++, xcode

So I've declared my class, "index", in the file index.h thusly:

```
#ifndef INDEX_H
#define INDEX_H

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include "word.h"
#include "heap.h"

using namespace std;

class index
{
public:
    index();
    ~index();
    index(const index &other);

    index& operator = (const index &other);
    void push(word<string> w);
    word<string> pop();

private:
    heap<word<string> > orchard[26];
    void nukem();
    void copy(const index &other);
};

#endif
```

And the subsequent definition:

```
#include "index.h"


index::index()
{}

index::~index()
{
    nukem();
}

index::index(const index &other)
{
    copy(other);
}


index& index::operator = (const index &other)
{
    if(this != &other)
        copy(other);
    return *this;
}

void index::push(word<string> w)
{
    orchard[w.data[0]]<<w;
}

word<string> index::pop()
{
    word<string> popped;
    int i = 0;
    for(; orchard[i].empty(); i++);
    orchard[i]>>popped;
    return popped;
}

void index::nukem()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        orchard[i].clear();
}

void index::copy(const index &other)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        orchard[i] = other.orchard[i];
}
```

In the definition of the assignment operator, I get this compiler error from xcode:

> Expected constructor, destructor or type conversion before '&' token

Which made me think it was a type problem, so I deleted the '&' and tried to recompile, which gave me this error on the same line:

> 'index' is not a type

Both errors appear on the first line of the following code:

```
index& index::operator = (const index &other)
{
    if(this != &other)
        copy(other);
    return *this;
}
```

Why is the compiler not recognizing that index is a type declared in the header file? I've looked back at previous classes I've written and can't see where I'm going wrong. I think it's probably a bonehead mistake, but I'm not seeing it. All help is appreciated.

Comment: Cannot reproduce (g++ 4.8.1)

Comment: Have you tried compiling this with `g++`?

Comment: Looks okay -- maybe a missing semicolon or bracket in `heap.h` or `word.h`?

Comment: may i suggest to get rid of the `using namespace std;` in the headers?  maybe it find other index elsewhere? you can try `using std::string;` instead.